# Difference between websocket and websockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I don't understand the difference between websocket (websocket client) and websockets.
I would like to understand the difference to know which one uses to be optimal.

I have a code that seems to do the same thing.

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import json

async def capture_data():
    uri = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=instrument:XBTUSD"
    #uri = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.recv()
            data = json.loads(data)
            try :
                #print('\n', data['data'][0]["lastPrice"])
                print('\n', data)
            except KeyError:
                continue


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(capture_data())
```

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")

    auth_data = {
        'op': 'subscribe',
        'args': ['instrument:XBTUSD']
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(auth_data))

def on_message(ws, message):
    message = json.loads(message)
    print(message)

def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")


socket = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime"                 
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, 
                            on_open=on_open, 
                            on_message=on_message,
                            on_close=on_close)     
ws.run_forever()
```

EDIT:

Is Python powerful enough to receive a lot of data via websocket?
In times of high traffic, I could have thousands of messages per second and even tens of thousands for short periods of time.

I've seen a lot of things about Nodejs that might be better than python but I don't know js and even if I just copy code from the internet I'm not sure I wouldn't waste time if I have to send the data to my python script and then process it.

Comment: Just came across this, honestly I feel as if there is very little difference, just two means to an ends, I do like the callback functionality you can specify WebSocketApp(), quite intuitive to read.

Answer (score 5):

`websocket-client` implements only client-side. If you want to create a WebSocket Server you have to use `websockets`.

`websocket-client` implements WebSocketApp which is more JavaScript like implementation of websocket.

I prefer WebSocketApp run as thread:

```py
socket = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime"                 
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, 
                            on_open=on_open, 
                            on_message=on_message,
                            on_close=on_close) 

wst = threading.Thread(target=lambda: ws.run_forever())
wst.daemon = True
wst.start()

# your code continues here ...
```

Now you have asynchronous WebSocket. Your mainframe program is running and every time, when you receive the message, function `on_message` is called. `on_message` process the message automatically, without mainframe interruption.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "JavaScript like implementation" ?

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) of Javascript Websocket, you create objects and assign event listeners for on_message, on_close, and so on. These listeners work asynchronously.

Comment: I still don't see how that is relevant to the main question which is the difference `websocket-client` module and `websockets` module?

Comment: Websocket is a communication protocol. Both libs websockets and websockets provides API for this protocol. Main difference is in mentioned API. What kind of difference do you expect? Or what kind of answer will satisfy you?

Comment: I'm currently using the `websockets` module in python but I'm wondering whether it would be better for me to use the `websocket-client` module instead. I would like to understand if there is a benefit of using one over the other?

Comment: It really depends on your application design. Package `webscoket-client` provide only WebSocket-client. If you want to create WebSocket server you have to use `websockets` (for server side). Consumer can be `webscoket-client`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That's a significant difference although not relevant for me as i only use the client and not the server. I guess I'll just have to experiment with `webscoket-client` at some point to see if there's any real benefit or disadvantage of using that over `websockets`. The issue for me really is when I'm looking for solutions on stackoverflow relating to websockets I come across examples with  `webscoket-client` which makes them harder to understand as I'm not familiar with that implementation.

Comment: Therefore I think `websocket-client` will be easier for you. Just create connection, define methods that will be triggered on a particular event and that's all. If you will have some specific issue ask question on SO, and I can help.

Comment: I am using websocket-client, WebsocketApp in a thread just like in your example. Do you know how we can handle reconnection when the connection is lost due to some error?

Comment: you have to create another service which will control if the connection is active. If is closed must reconnect your websocket-client

Answer (score 5):

So I had a lot of confusion about this as well.  There are three libraries/packages that are being talked about.

1. Websocket , the native python low-level protocol useful for advanced users building custom protocols on top of WebSocket or for building custom servers.
2. Websocket-client, a client-side only app from which you can use .WebSocketApp is a mid-level library with a simplified API for working with WebSocket clients. It is easier to use than websocket and a separate pip install.
3. Websockets , with an 's', which is a higher level library built around asyncio that provides both client and server implementations of the WebSocket protocol. It is the most modern and feature-rich and is a good choice if you need asyncio support or advanced features like SSL/TLS encryption, compression, or per-message deflate.

Websocket does not play well with asyncio; one would presume Websocket-client might be the same (no info I can find), but Websockets is built around it.

Presumably you are asking about streaming data (video, music, financial) coming from the websocket - You'll just have to try it but I would anticipate financial data would be the easiest unless you are trying to load all symbols and all quotes from an exchange on a nanosecond scale which might be a bit much.  Try it out and see what the practical limitations are and consider filtering.

Answer (score 2):

[websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/) is a Python standard libary, currently suggested to use.

As far as I understand the main difference, from the client API programming, is that [websocket-client](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) support callbacks programming paradigm, in a way similar of javascript web client APIs.

Read the websockets documentation [FAQs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/faq.html#are-there-onopen-onmessage-onerror-and-onclose-callbacks):

> **Are there onopen, onmessage, onerror, and onclose callbacks?**
>
> No, there aren’t.
>
> websockets provides high-level, coroutine-based APIs. Compared to callbacks, coroutines make it easier to manage control flow in concurrent code.
>
> If you prefer callback-based APIs, you should use another library.

With current Python 3 release the common / suggested way to manage asyncronous coroutines is via asyncio (used by websockets standard library approach).

So, answering your last question (Python vs nodejs), [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) just allows to manage asyncronous I/O (networking-based in this case) events, as NodeJs does natively. broadley speaking, using asyncio you can achieve I/O websockets performances similar to that obtained using Nodejs.